# Fourier font and enumitem misbehaviour

Tags: enumitem, fourier

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=10pt,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=30.5pt,leftmargin=!,itemsep=2.00pt,topsep=2.75pt,partopsep=2.00pt,parsep=2.00pt,label=\Alph*.,ref=\Alph{enumi}]
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Clearly, the letters are not correctly aligned. See the pic below (particularly the letter F).

[image: BAD ALIGNMENT]

If instead one runs the exact same MWE but commenting `\usepackage{fourier}`, one obtains correctly aligned letters. See the pic below.

[image: GOOD ALIGNMENT]

Why is this happening? Can this problem be sorted in any way?

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the issue must arise from the kerning between, for example, `F` and the subsequent period `.`  Therefore, I prevent the kerning by typesetting the label as `label={\Alph*}.`, with braces, so that kerning between the letter and the dot does not apply.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=10pt,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=30.5pt,leftmargin=!,itemsep=2.00pt,topsep=2.75pt,
  partopsep=2.00pt,parsep=2.00pt,label={\Alph*}.,ref=\Alph{enumi}]
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are still not happy, you can center the letter in a fixed-width `\makebox`, as in `label={\makebox[1.6ex]{\Alph*}.}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=10pt,labelwidth=0pt,labelsep=30.5pt,leftmargin=!,itemsep=2.00pt,topsep=2.75pt,
  partopsep=2.00pt,parsep=2.00pt,label={\makebox[1.6ex]{\Alph*}.},ref=\Alph{enumi}]
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
    \item Do whatever.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I adopted your second approach: it's the one that feels visually best (at least to me). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In order to break an automatic kerning, I suggest `\/`, which inserts an explicit kern, so disallowing the automatic one.

```
\begin{enumerate}[
  labelindent=10pt,
  labelwidth=0pt,
  labelsep=30.5pt,
  leftmargin=!,
  itemsep=2.00pt,
  topsep=2.75pt,
  partopsep=2.00pt,
  parsep=2.00pt,
  label=\Alph*\/.,
  ref=\Alph{enumi}
]
```

I believe you should define your own environment, instead of adding all those options in the document body.

[image]

You may also want to do

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{erewhon}
```

which chooses a newer version of Utopia for the text font, with better support for font encodings.

Comment: Unless you really *like* `fourier` for math (personally, I think it's a train wreck!) you might also try `\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath}` (`utopia` was Adobe's font name for what evolved into `erewhon`).

Comment: @alephzero I never got notified of this comment. Why is ``fourier`` such a disaster, if I may ask? I'll give a try to your suggestion to see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Héctor I'm not sure why alephzero put here his/her comment. When you want to address a comment to somebody who participated to the discussion, start the comment with `@`, press TAB and choose the appropriate completion. I wrote a book with Fourier.

Comment: @egreg I never thought much about it... I certainly like it since I first saw it. So unless it turns out there is a *solid* reason to give it up, I think I will stick to it. Now I'm curious.