# Should one use fourier with erewhon?

Tags: fonts, ligatures, fourier

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{erewhon}

\begin{document}

This is my offer.

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:

[image]

If instead one comments `\usepackage{erewhon}`, one obtains this other result:

[image]

Look at the **ff** of the word 'offer'. It's obvious that they differ. Other than that, though, I haven't found much difference between using `fourier` alone or `fourier` with `erewhon` (they're just slightly, very slightly, different). Then, my question is three-fold:

1. What's the case for `fourier` and the case for `fourier` plus `erewhon`?
2. Is this different **ff** intended or buggy?
3. If intended, which of the **ff** is typographically better, if any (and for what reasons)?

PS: the question comes from @egreg's suggestion in her [answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453781/fourier-font-and-enumitem-misbehaviour), but I thought that asking this here could be useful to other `fourier` potential users.

Thank you all very much in advanced for your time.

Comment: 2. This is intended, not buggy, and called ligature. 3. Ligatures are usually considered superior typography.

Comment: From your comment it seems that: 1. the case for `fourier` alone is none and that all cases are indeed for `fourier` with `erewhon`...

Comment: Probably, but I'm afraid to say that without knowing the details about these packages.

Comment: It looks like both are just font packages. `fourier` includes math fonts, `erewhon` does not. But the text font, provided by both, is kind of "overwritten" by the last package loaded.

Comment: An ff ligature is part of the Utopia expert fonts although it's different from the one supplied by the erehwon (nowhere spelled backward if you didn't notice) font. The erehwon documentation explicitly says that it supplies some missing ligatures for the Utopia fonts used by the fourier package.

Comment: The `erewhon` documentation recommends `\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath}` as the matching math font, not `fourier.` Personally I don't think `fourier` has much to recommend it, visually - but YMMV of course.

Comment: I think there is enough information in the comments for someone to post a short reply answering the three questions and suggesting to use ``\usepackage[utopia]{fourier}``. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is really old and none of those who commented posted an answer, I'll do it myself. Given the comments to the OP, I would say that the best approach is to use

```
\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{erewhon}
```

This is the font setup I use in most of my documents and I'm very happy with it.